# Joint Density of Bernoulli

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, density-function

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be iid $Bern(p)$. Let $f$ be the joint density of $(X_1,X_2)$, so
$f(x_1,x_2)=P(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2)$.

What is $f(1,0)$?

---

Since a bernoulli is $p$ at $1$ and $1-p$ at $0$, is $f(1,0) = p(1-p)$?

Comment: Bernoulli distributions have probability mass functions, not densities.  Apart from that, you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be right, specifically because of the independence of the variables. Thus when I have a joint probability,
$$P(X_1 = x_1, X_2 = x_2) = P(X_1 = x_1)P(X_2 = x_2).$$